# Problem With Recursion (categories and subcategories)

Tags: magento-1.9, category, category-tree

I'm testing a code from the answer by @digitalsteez on this question:

> [Get Categories and Its Sub Categories](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/36674/get-categories-and-its-sub-categories)

I've tested it onto two Magento instance, one has no problems but on the other I'm facing a problem with recursion:

```
"children" => getChildCategories($child)
```

and

```
renderCategoriesTree($level, $child);
```

output me an

> "Invalid argument supplied for `foreach()`"

How can I solve this?

Thank You in advice.